# pandas dataframe to custom nested json

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a pandas dataframe that looks like this:

```
user_id     cat_id  prod_id    score    pref_prod
    29762       9   3115      1.000000   335.0
    29762       58  1335      1.000000   335.0
    234894      58  1335      1.000000   335.0
    413276      43  1388      1.000000   335.0
    413276      58  1335      1.000000   335.0
    413276      73  26        1.000000   335.0
    9280593     9   137       1.000000   335.0
    9280593     58  1335      1.000000   335.0
    9280593     74  160       1.000000   335.0
    4554542     66  1612      0.166667   197.0
    4554542     66  1406      0.166767   197.0
    4554542     66  2021      1.000000   197.0
```

I want to group this df by `user_id` & `cat_id` and convert it to json so that it looks something like this:

```
{
    29762: {
        'cat_id': {
            9: [{
                'prod_id': 3115,
                'score': 1.0
            }],
            58: [{
                'prod_id': 1335,
                'score': 1.0
            }]
        },
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }
    234894: {
        'cat_id': {
            58: [{
                'prod_id': 1335,
                'score': 1.0
            }]
        },
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }
    413276: {
        'cat_id': {
            43: [{
                'prod_id': 1388,
                'score': 1.0,
                'fav_provider': 335.0
            }],
            58: [{
                'prod_id': 1335,
                'score': 1.0,
                'fav_provider': 335.0
            }],
            73: [{
                'prod_id': 26,
                'score': 1.0,
            }]
        },
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }
    4554542: {
        'cat_id': {
            66: [{
                'prod_id': 1612,
                'score': 0.166
            }, {
                'prod_id': 1406,
                'score': 0.16
            }, {
                'prod_id': 2021,
                'score': 1.0,
            }]
        },
        'pref_prod': 197.0
    }
}
```

As of now I can do

```
gb = df.groupby(['user_id', 'cat_id']).apply(lambda g: g.drop(['user_id', 'cat_id'], axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()
```

which gives me user_id and cat_id in tuple keys:

```
{
    (29762, 9): [{
        'prod_id': 3115,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (29762, 58): [{
        'prod_id': 1335,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (234894, 58): [{
        'prod_id': 1335,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (413276, 43): [{
        'prod_id': 1388,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (413276, 58): [{
        'prod_id': 1335,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (413276, 73): [{
        'prod_id': 26,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (9280593, 9): [{
        'prod_id': 137,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (9280593, 58): [{
        'prod_id': 1335,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (9280593, 74): [{
        'prod_id': 160,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 335.0
    }],
    (4554542,
        66): [{
        'prod_id': 1612,
        'score': 0.16666666666666666,
        'pref_prod': 197.0
    }, {
        'prod_id': 1406,
        'score': 0.16676666666666665,
        'pref_prod': 197.0
    }, {
        'prod_id': 2021,
        'score': 1.0,
        'pref_prod': 197.0
    }]
}
```

How can I get the json in the desired format

Answer (score 0):

I can't think of any direct way to do it with `pandas` only. But you can construct a new dictionary with the desired format based on `gb`, using a `defaultdict`

```
from collections import defaultdict 
import json  # just to prettyprint the resulting dictionary 

gb = df.groupby(['user_id', 'cat_id']).apply(lambda g: g.drop(['user_id', 'cat_id'], axis=1).to_dict(orient='records')).to_dict()

d = defaultdict(lambda: {'cat_id':{}} )

for (user_id, cat_id), records in gb.items():
    for record in records:
        # drop 'pref_prod' key of each record
        # I'm assuming its unique for each (user_id, cat_id) group
        pref_prod = record.pop('pref_prod')
    d[user_id]['cat_id'][cat_id] = records
    d[user_id]['pref_prod'] = pref_prod

>>> print(json.dumps(d, indent=4))

{
    "29762": {
        "cat_id": {
            "9": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 3115,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ],
            "58": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1335,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "pref_prod": 335.0
    },
    "234894": {
        "cat_id": {
            "58": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1335,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "pref_prod": 335.0
    },
    "413276": {
        "cat_id": {
            "43": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1388,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ],
            "58": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1335,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ],
            "73": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 26,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "pref_prod": 335.0
    },
    "4554542": {
        "cat_id": {
            "66": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1612,
                    "score": 0.166667
                },
                {
                    "prod_id": 1406,
                    "score": 0.166767
                },
                {
                    "prod_id": 2021,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "pref_prod": 197.0
    },
    "9280593": {
        "cat_id": {
            "9": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 137,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ],
            "58": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 1335,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ],
            "74": [
                {
                    "prod_id": 160,
                    "score": 1.0
                }
            ]
        },
        "pref_prod": 335.0
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I used a namedtuple from a dataframe conversion to create the json tree.  if the tree has more than one level than I would use recursion to build it.  the dataframe did not contain lists of list so recursion was not required.

```
from io import StringIO
import io
from collections import namedtuple  
data="""user_id,cat_id,prod_id,score,pref_prod
29762,9,3115,1.000000,335.0
29762,58,1335,1.000000,335.0
234894,58,1335,1.000000,335.0
413276,43,1388,1.000000,335.0
413276,58,335,1.000000,335.0
413276,73,26,1.000000,335.0
9280593,9,137,1.000000,335.0
9280593,58,1335,1.000000,335.0
9280593,74,160,1.000000,335.0
4554542,66,1612,0.166667,197.0
4554542,66,1406,0.166767,197.0
4554542,66,2021,1.000000,197.0"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), sep=',')

Record=namedtuple('Generic',['user_id','cat_id','prod_id','score','pref_prod'])

def map_to_record(row):
    return Record(row.user_id, row.cat_id, row.prod_id,row.score,row.pref_prod)

my_list = list(map(map_to_record, df.itertuples()))

def named_tuple_to_json(named_tuple):
"""
    convert a named tuple to a json tree structure
"""
    json_string="records:["
    for record in named_tuple:
        json_string+="{"
        json_string+="'user_id': {},'cat_id': {},'prod_id': {},'score': {},'pref_prod': {},".format(
    record.user_id,record.cat_id,record.prod_id,record.score,record.pref_prod)
        json_string+="},"
    json_string+="]"
    return json_string

# convert the list of named tuples to a json tree structure
json_tree = named_tuple_to_json(my_list)
print(json_tree)
```

output

records:[{'user_id': 29762,'cat_id': 9,'prod_id': 3115,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 29762,'cat_id': 58,'prod_id': 1335,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 234894,'cat_id': 58,'prod_id': 1335,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 413276,'cat_id': 43,'prod_id': 1388,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 413276,'cat_id': 58,'prod_id': 335,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 413276,'cat_id': 73,'prod_id': 26,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 9280593,'cat_id': 9,'prod_id': 137,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 9280593,'cat_id': 58,'prod_id': 1335,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 9280593,'cat_id': 74,'prod_id': 160,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 335.0,},{'user_id': 4554542,'cat_id': 66,'prod_id': 1612,'score': 0.166667,'pref_prod': 197.0,},{'user_id': 4554542,'cat_id': 66,'prod_id': 1406,'score': 0.166767,'pref_prod': 197.0,},{'user_id': 4554542,'cat_id': 66,'prod_id': 2021,'score': 1.0,'pref_prod': 197.0,},]
​